# Using an animator to create a flashing effect

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

So I have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="backgroundColor"
            android:duration="100"
            android:repeatCount="-1"
            android:repeatMode="reverse"
            android:valueFrom="@color/light_blue"
            android:valueTo="@color/blue"/>

</set>
```

And I am running it on an `ImageButton` like so.

```
AnimatorSet set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(appContext,
                R.animator.invitation_animator);
            set.setTarget(actionInvitation);
            set.start();
```

I want it to flash from light blue to blue again but instead, it's gradually fading between colors. I am using this animation as a notification to the user when he/she gets an invitation, that's why i'd like a flashing effect.

Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to shorten your animation's duration. The best way to do this would be to first try:

```
android:duration="50"
```

Then if you need shorter gaps, half it:

```
android:duration="25"
```

or increase it if that was too quick:

```
android:duration="75"
```

etc, until you get the effect you are seeking.

Comment: I've already tried that it doesnt really flash, its just alot faster and has some sort of hippy effect like im on acid